# Estimate for the product of primes less than n (again)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It has been mentioned in this question [Estimate for the product of primes less than n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204902/estimate-for-the-product-of-primes-less-than-n) that:

> In this [paper](http://www.math-inst.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1989-29.pdf) Erdős shows a shorter proof for one of his old
> results stating that $$ s(n) = \prod_{p < n} p < 4^n$$ where the
> product is taken over all primes less than $n$. He also remarks that
> using the prime number theorem one can show
> $$ s(n)^{\frac1n} \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} e.$$
>
> Can someone here prove this result? It does not seem straightforward
> to me.

There was an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/204909/26632 but it's more the idea than a rigorous proof.

So I'm posting the question again, how to prove it? Best if it can be done in an elementary way.

Comment: Start with $\prod_{n<p\le 2n}p \le {2n \choose n} = \frac{2n (2n-1)}{n^2} {2(n-1) \choose (n-1)}\le 4 {2(n-1) \choose (n-1)}\le 4^n$ and $\prod_{p\le 4^x}p =\prod_{m\ge 1}(\prod_{4^{x/2^m}<p\le 4^{x/2^{m-1}}} p)$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the prime number theorem, i.e. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi(n)\,\ln n}n=1,$$ the proof is elementary, using just the following simple fact (cf. [Convergence of the arithmetic mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533626/convergence-of-the-arithmetic-mean)):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{k=1}a_k}n=0$.

With $$\theta(n)=\sum_{p \leq n,\,p\,\text{prime}} \ln p,$$
we have to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\theta(n)}n=1.$$Now (via partial summation), $$\theta(n)=\sum^n_{k=1} (\pi(k)-\pi(k-1))\,\ln k=\pi(n)\,\ln(n+1)-\sum^n_{k=1}\pi(k)\,\ln\left(1+\frac1k\right)$$ Obviously,
$$a_n=\pi(n)\,\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=n\,\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\cdot\frac{\pi(n)\,\ln n}n\cdot\frac1{\ln n}\to1\cdot1\cdot0=0$$as $n\to\infty$, so
$$\frac{\theta(n)}n=\frac{\pi(n)\,\ln n}n\cdot\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}-\frac1n\,\sum^n_{k=1}a_k\to1\cdot1-0=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$s(n) = \prod \limits_{p \leq n} p$ so $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s(n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{p \leq n} \ln p}$

And we have $ \theta(n) = \sum \limits_{p \leq n} \ln p$ and by the PNT we have that $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\theta(n)}{n} =1 $

So $e^{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{p \leq n} \ln p} = e^{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\theta(n)}{n}} = e^{1} = e $

Comment: I thought Prime number theorem only states (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement) $\lim _{x\to \infty }{\frac {\;\pi (x)\;}{\;\left[{\frac {x}{\log(x)}}\right]\;}}=1$, it doesn't talk about $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\theta(n)}{n}  $?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{p \leq n} \ln p$?

Comment: @athos exactly in the same paper look 3 or 4 lines below to see this equivalent to PNT.

Comment: @ProfessorVector yes, I will fix it.