# An unsolvable Number Theory Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question I was sent by a friend, I really have zero idea on how to solve the question. I'm not even sure where to begin solving it. Though I did make an attempt to solve it, I always reached a dead end.

So here's the question:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $1$ and let $p_1, p_2, ... p_t$ be the primes **not exceeding $n$**.
>   Show that $p_1p_2...p_t < 4^n$

Comment: This has already been solved at Stack Exchange:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15902/show-that-product-of-primes-prod-k-1-pin-p-k-4n

Comment: Interesting that always a "friend" is the source of this problem :)

Comment: Oh, that's awesome, Thanks for letting me know, @user2584283